# Execute function X times and return resultset in Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, function

I have SQL Server background and currently working on Oracle database so please bear with me with different terminology or lack of basic Oracle knowledge.

In Oracle 12, I have a function "ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE_SQL.GET_NEXT(O_ERROR_MESSAGE, IO_ITEM_NO, I_ITEM_TYPE);" If it succeeds, it returns true/false and populates the "IO_ITEM_NO" variable/parameter. If error occurs, it will populate "O_ERROR_MESSAGE" variable/parameter. As of now I can successfully execute this function and get the value by using .Net application which returns the next item number (i.e. IO_ITEM_NO). .Net application already knows how many item numbers it requires and executes this function multiple times on the .Net application side (and not on oracle side) but it takes too much time (~ > 0.5 second per function call even with same connection) as the .Net application box is geographically separate from oracle box.

How can I execute this function X number of times on Oracle side and store the IO_ITEM_NO values into a temporary table/storage on Oracle side and retrieve the result set on the .Net side using just one call?

The user executing this function will have only execute and read permission and it is not possible to create objects on Oracle side unless it is a part of execute/read permission. (for example in SQL server, user with read permission can create temporary tables but not permanent tables)

Here is a pseudo code.

```
DECLARE  v_bool BOOLEAN;
DECLARE O_ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(200);
DECLARE IO_ITEM_NO VARCHAR2(25);
DECLARE COUNT INT;
DECLARE TEMP_TABLE TABLE AS (ITEM_NO VARCHAR2(25));
BEGIN
                COUNT := 10; -- Means we need to execute ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE_SQL.GET_NEXT function 10 times
                FOR i IN 1 .. COUNT
                                v_bool := ITEM_NUMBER_TYPE_SQL.GET_NEXT(O_ERROR_MESSAGE, IO_ITEM_NO, 'ITEM');
                                IF(v_bool = TRUE) 
                                                THEN SELECT 1 INTO :v_Return FROM DUAL; 
                                                -- Following statement inserts the IO_ITEM_NO value which was returned from the function into the temp table
                                                INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE (ITEM_NO)
                                                SELECT IO_ITEM_NO FROM DUAL; 
                                END IF;
                                IF(v_bool = FALSE) THEN 
                                                SELECT 0 INTO :v_Return FROM DUAL; 
                                                i := 10; -- Breaking the loop as error encountered
                                END IF;
                END LOOP;
                -- Finally send the resultset back
                SELECT ITEM_NO FROM TEMP_TABLE;
END;
```

Comment: Well, you don't show what your function does, but can't you just open a cursor and return the result set?

Comment: It is a 3rd party application and function was provided as a part of application. I don't want to recreate logic and/or add additional objects unless it is temporary to a session like temp tables in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Oracle is very different from MSSQL. You should catch any attempt to 'make as in MSSQL' and check 'how this issue should be made with Oracle'. Most common error is trying to use temporary tables as of in MSSQL.

Second, multiple calls for a single task is bad decision everywhere. It should be avoided if possible.

Generally, it looks like Oracle's [pipelined functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm) are designed for exact this task. These functions can return resultset on row-per-row basis, until your function returns false. It would something like  this:

```
select * from table(my_table_function(10));

function my_table_function(limit integer) is
begin
  while get_next(...) loop
    pipe row(some_data_returned);
  end loop;
end;
```

And yet another thing: in Oracle "O_ERROR_MESSAGE" is bad design. You should use exceptions instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not attempting to "make as in MSSQL" and want to do it Oracle way.

I asked this question to find a way to avoid multiple calls as I am new to Oracle.

Your answer seems like wants me to create a function which I mentioned that I don't have a luxury due to permission.

Design of "O_ERROR_MESSAGE" came as a 3rd party application. This application is Oracle Retail developed and designed by Oracle and cannot change it.